# Is taking higher HP classes first better?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, multi-classing, hit-points

**When multi-classing in Pathfinder, is it strictly better to take a higher HP class at first level?**

**At first level, your character gets max HP for the HD of their class.**  At subsequent levels, you roll the HD (or take the preset average roll in alternate rules).

This was also true in earlier versions of 3rd Edition; however, these editions also granted ×4 skill points, as well as a bigger initial maximum skill rank to be filled with them.  Thus, there used to be some trade-off between which class you would take first.

As an example, if you planned on leveling up as equal levels of Fighter and Rogue, you could either start with Fighter for the extra HP, or start with Rogue for the far superior skills.  A *Fighter 1 / Rogue 1* could end up very different from a *Rogue 1 / Fighter 1* for this reason, and both had advantages.

From what I can tell, **Pathfinder** seems to have **removed** all of these aspects of skills that would give an **advantage to taking a skill-based class first.**  Is this the case?  Or, are there any other advantages to the ordering that I am overlooking?

This is naturally from the perspective of build optimization; it does not factor in the act of playing such a character in-between leveling up.

Can this be fixed with a simple house rule?  It seems to me that, for instance, one could retroactively adjust a character's HP if they multi-class into a new class that has a higher HD than any other they've had before, taking max on that HD and re-rolling the one that used to be max instead.  Are there any significant issues with this method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, your first class has the advantage of a maximized HD, which none of the following classes share. At worst, this is a difference of 6 hp—if you were choosing between a d6 and a d12—which isn’t *that* much even at low levels, and eventually becomes nearly inconsequential.

Still, there *is* a meta-advantage to having your high-HD classes first, that makes them *strictly* superior. There is no countering advantages that other classes may have, as high-skill classes in D&D 3/3.5e enjoyed. (In theory, needing a *lot* of skill ranks for a feat or prestige class could force you to delay a high-HD, low-skill class until later, but I can’t think of any major examples that would put one in such a situation. This, too, was more likely in D&D 3/3.5e due to the doubled costs and lower maximum rank for cross-class skills in those.)

So your houserule would address that issue and eliminate it, removing the meta-incentive to order your classes in a particular way. That seems good to me, and I recommend it. However, I strongly recommend using average values rather than actually rolling HD. Nineteen rolls has a reasonably high probability of evening things out by 20th, but since most games are played solely at lower levels, pure luck could have extremely advantageous or disadvantageous effects on a character when rolling HD. Since these rolls are rare, permanent, and critical, they represent an extreme form of the [goblin dice problem](http://ponderingsongames.com/2013/01/27/goblin-dice/). Much better to avoid it.

Comment: We're already using the average-rolls system (actually, average-rounded-up to avoid decimal points entirely), which I also prefer immensely.  We're also playing E6 where 6th Level is the level cap, so I would argue that 6 HP can still be pretty significant.

Comment: @SouthpawHare Sure, but none of that is intrinsic in the question and the answer should be for all readers. At 6th level, yeah, 6 hp is still pretty meaningful.

Comment: I agree.  I don't think you should change your answer.  Just letting you know.

Comment: I think the only issue that may arise is with favored class benefits if the picked favored class isn't the first class a creature takes.

Comment: @HeyICanChan That is a rarer issue though, I think.  In my example, for instance, the person is leveling up two classes evenly, which would never result in a problem there.  I suppose if you wanted to be extra-friendly, you could apply some sort of retroactive rule for favored class as well (it becomes whatever you have the most levels in), but I don't think I'm going to have a problem with that.

Comment: One house rule I've heard of is where you roll first then if less than average take average, if more than average take roll. I feel this can give the best of both worlds and mean you don't get wimpy 3rd level rogue with 11 hp but also keeps the sense of randomness in the game.

Comment: @rpgstar I don’t agree *at all*. There is plenty of randomness in the game in all the rolls you make for attempting to do things. Rolling for permanent stats is just far too weighty a matter to leave up to dice. It’s bad for the game. Your houserule eliminates the possibility of too-bad luck, but not of too-good luck, which can also be problematic.

Comment: @KRyan I guess that's why its a house rule and not RAW. It works in some groups but not in others the same as all house rules.

Comment: @rpgstar While I agree with KRyan that literally *rolling up a character* is bad for precariously balanced games like these, I nonetheless have otherwise smart folks at my *D&D 3.5e* table who insist on rolling for hit points after level 1 despite my preference that they don't. (I make both methods of hp determination available.) They most often opt to roll on a low-average hp level when the class has a low Hit Die (The difference between a *3.5* wizard's 1 and 2 on a d4 is minor but between 2 and 4 is more significant, for instance.)

Comment: This answer may be improved by discussing "Retraining" for HP. Though it's not something that all groups have access to, it *does* make it so that the order you take your levels in is irrelevant for the purposes of HP. Has major problems of its own, though, namely making downtime a powerspike compared to non-downtime games.

Comment: @Forrestfire I am not familiar with/don’t use those rules, so I think that would be better handled by someone else adding an answer about it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few exceptions, although the ones I can think of are all very minor/situational:

## 1: Starting money

Since different classes roll different dice for starting wealth (CRB p. 140) combinations like ranger/barbarian could increase starting wealth by as much as 2d6x10, average 70 GP by starting in the lower-HP class. That's enough to buy 140 days of rations, or put down a 20% deposit on a masterwork greatsword!

It's a terrible trade-off, but it is *something* in exchange for the -1 HP (average) from taking this option.

Strict enforcement of the Wealth-By-Level guidelines would make this irrelevant from level 2 onwards, but strict enforcement is hard to achieve.

## 2: Bonus languages

Starting in cleric, druid, or wizard expands the list of bonus languages that you can take. Consider a dwarf cleric/fighter who rolled Int 16, and who wants to speak Abyssal, Celestial, and Fiendish in order to communicate with summoned creatures. Taking cleric first makes it possible to spend the bonus picks on these languages, saving three skill points at the cost of one HP (and whatever other languages you might have spent the bonus picks on).

If you're using the retraining rules, you *could* spend money to learn extra languages without spending skill points, but it'd be much cheaper just to retrain your hit points.

## 3: Finessing feat prereq chains

For example, say I want to build a non-human fighter 1/monk 1 with the feat Snatch Arrows.

If I go monk-first, I can reach this feat at level 1: Improved Unarmed Strike as standard monk bonus feat, Deflect Arrows from my chooseable monk bonus feat, and then Snatch Arrows with my standard level 1 feat. Then when I hit level 2 and take a level of fighter, I can spend the fighter bonus feat on something that has IUS as a prereq, e.g. Improved Grapple.

On the other hand, if I take fighter first, I cannot get Snatch Arrows even at level 2, because the monk bonus feats are only useful for satisfying prereqs if I can get them *before* the final feat that I spend on Snatch Arrows.

Again, you *could* retrain the feat, but this is more expensive than just retraining for the hit point you traded off.

Comment: It’s worth noting that starting money should have no effect on the game by 2nd level—the wealth-by-level guidelines would have all wealth even out by then.

Comment: @KRyan I think I did note that?

Comment: Ah, no, not quite—even if you don’t *start* at higher level, the guidelines suggest that you should all even out by the time you get to 2nd, even if you start at different places. Which is kind of weird (implies that the party is supposed to divide loot unequally to make that happen), but it is what the guidelines suggest.

Comment: Oh, right. Fair point, I'll edit that.

Comment: @KRyan *Divided unequally* in this case means, "Hey, let's give the wizard a little extra walkin' around money," right? I mean, we're talkin', like, a pittance here, aren't we?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I mean, it could end up being a few pieces of platinum, which is, ya know, quite a lot of money for the average joe.

Comment: @KRyan Surely, you jest, equating an *average joe* to a mighty *Pathfinder* PC! (Seriously, my calculations have even an untrained 1st-level average joe actually earning 5 gp/week, the game's 1 sp/day to the contrary, *via* practicing a trade using the Craft skill. Thus an adventurer with *no* skills who gets a *real* job for a few weeks should be able to make up the difference in starting cash between him and his buddies. And *now* I'm tempted to start everyone at the same highest starting gold and just have normally poorer PCs be gainfully employed prior to entering play!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan and then we start bickering about whether the wizard's spellbook and inscribed spells should be counted towards net worth, even though they're not bought out of starting gold...

Comment: The classes with most starting gold are usually those with highest hp, which need the gold most for starting equipment (weapons and armor). You did mention retraining, but you did not explain howmuch more expensive it is.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I was actually referring more to the unlikelihood that players would naturally decide to split funds so as to exactly even things out, than to the actual magnitude of the difference. Players are far more likely to evenly split income than to figure out that someone started with less and so deserves (?) a bigger share of the pot.